# Converting a string encoded in utf8 to unicode in C#

Tags: c#, encoding

I've got this string returned via HTTP Post from a URL in a C# application, that contains some chinese character eg:

```
GelatosÂ® Colors Gift Setä¸­æ–‡
```

Problem is I want to convert it to

```
Gelatos® Colors Gift Set中文
```

Both string are actually identical but encoded differently. I understand in C# everything is UTF16. I've tried reading alof of postings here regarding converting from one encoding to the other but no luck.

Hope someone could help.

Here's the C# code:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
json = wc.DownloadString("http://mysite.com/ext/export.asp");

textBox2.Text = "Receiving orders....";

//convert the string to UTF16
        Encoding ascii = Encoding.ASCII;
        Encoding unicode = Encoding.Unicode;
        Encoding utf8 = Encoding.UTF8;

        byte[] asciiBytes = ascii.GetBytes(json);
        byte[] utf8Bytes = utf8.GetBytes(json);
        byte[] unicodeBytes = Encoding.Convert(utf8, unicode, utf8Bytes);

        string sOut = unicode.GetString(unicodeBytes);

System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(sOut);  //doesn't work...
```

Here's the code from the server:

```
<%@CodePage = 65001%>
<%option explicit%>
<%
Session.CodePage = 65001
Response.charset ="utf-8"
Session.LCID     = 1033 'en-US
```

.....
    response.write (strJSON)

```
%>
```

The output from the web is correct. But I was just wondering if some changes is done on the http stream to the C# application.

thanks.

Comment: What conversion functions have you tried, and whats goes wrong?

Comment: Yip: Could you show us the code responsible for the HTTP POST that generates the string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the server is really returning UTF-8 text, you can configure your `WebClient` by setting its [`Encoding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.encoding.aspx) property. This would eliminate any need for subsequent conversions.

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    wc.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    json = wc.DownloadString("http://mysite.com/ext/export.asp");
}
```

Comment: Thanks Douglas....Finally get this right. The ASP does return UTF8, and  the C# will thus display the right string returned.

Answer (score 1):

Download the web pages as bytes in the first place. Then, convert the bytes to the correct encoding.

By first converting it using a wrong encoding you are probably losing data. Especially using ASCII.

Comment: thanks, but how do you download from a URL using a specific encoding?

Comment: Ok, got the download part using  byte[] response = new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadData(url);